# WordPress dynamic select with category and authors

Tags: categories, select, list-authors

I need to create two dynamic selects with PHP code to put in the functions.php file.

For the categories I'm using the following code which works great:

```
/* BLOG DYNAMIC CATEGORIES SELECT */
function blog_categories_select( $cat ) {
    // grab the current category object
    $current = get_the_category();
    $next = get_categories('hide_empty=false&orderby=name&order=ASC&parent=' . $cat);
    if( $next ) {  
        echo '<form name="catform" method="POST" action="" id="catform">
        <div class="select-caret-down-wrapper">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="eicon-caret-down"></i></div>
        <select name="catselect" class="blogselect" onchange="document.getElementById(\'catform\').setAttribute(\'action\', this.value); document.catform.submit(); ">
        <option value="">Categories</option>';
        foreach( $next as $cat ) {
            echo '<option value="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '"';
                // if the current category object matches the current ID of the iteration
                // add the selected attribute to the option element
                // if ($current[0]->term_id == $cat->term_id) {
                //    echo 'selected';
                // }
            echo '>' . $cat->name . '</option>';
            blog_categories_select( $cat->term_id );
        }
        echo '<option value="/blog/">All</option></select></form>';
    }
    echo "\n";
}  
add_shortcode('select-blog-category','blog_categories_select');
```

I have to do the same thing for authors. I modified the code as follows but it is clearly not working.

```
/* BLOG DYNAMIC AUTHORS SELECT */
function blog_authors_select( $aut ) {
    // grab the current category object
    $current = get_the_author();
    $next = get_the_author('hide_empty=false&orderby=name&order=ASC&parent=' . $aut);
    if( $next ) {  
        echo '<form name="autform" method="POST" action="" id="autform">
        <div class="select-caret-down-wrapper">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="eicon-caret-down"></i></div>
        <select name="autselect" class="blogselect" onchange="document.getElementById(\'autform\').setAttribute(\'action\', this.value); document.autform.submit(); ">
        <option value="">Authors</option>';
        foreach( $next as $aut ) {
            echo '<option value="' . get_author_posts_url( $aut->term_id ) . '"';
                // if the current category object matches the current ID of the iteration
                // add the selected attribute to the option element
                // if ($current[0]->term_id == $cat->term_id) {
                //    echo 'selected';
                // }
            echo '>' . $aut->name . '</option>';
            blog_authors_select( $aut->term_id );
        }
        echo '<option value="/blog/">All</option></select></form>';
    }
    echo "\n";
}  
add_shortcode('select-blog-author','blog_authors_select');
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed [get_the_author()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author/) returns the author of the current post. You'lle need to use [WP_User_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/) to get the authors.

E.g. `$author_query = new WP_User_Query( ['role' => 'Author'] );`

By default the query returns an array of [WP_User](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/) objects.